# If an CSV/ Excel file is open inform the user with a MessageBox and terminate the rest execution of the application [C# - WPF applcation]

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a method that calls an SQL Server stored procedure from a C# WPF application.

The method is the following:

```cs
public static int LoadFilesMethod(string connectionString, string ProcedureName, IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object> parameters, string filenamepath)
{
    using var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    sqlConnection.Open();

    using var command = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();

    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.CommandText = ProcedureName;

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> parameter in parameters)
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameter.Key, parameter.Value);
    }

    //Check if csv file is open!
    bool IsFileClose = CheckFileIsOpen(filenamepath); //return true or false if file is open
    CloseFileIfOpen(IsFileClose); //stops the application if false else continue
        
    //Executes the stored procedure if csv file is closed
    int NumbderOfRecords = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    sqlConnection.Close();

    return NumbderOfRecords;
}
```

Inside this method I call two other sub-methods which are called  `IsFileClose()` and `CloseFileIfOpen()` respectively.

**IsFileClose**

```cs
public static bool CheckFileIsOpen(string filenamepath)
{
   try
   {
      using (FileStream  fs = new FileStream(filenamepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
      {
          return true;
      }
      //Stream s = File.Open(filenamepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);   
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      MessageBox.Show("File is in use!! Close it and try again");
      return false;
   }
}
```

**CloseFileIfOpen**

```cs
public static void CloseFileIfOpen(bool value)
{
   if (value = false)
   {
      return;
   }
   else
   {
      return;
   }
}
```

I want the application to inform the user if the CSV/Excel file is open and to generate a `MessageBox` to inform him that the file is open so that to close it.

But before the application closes the file it should stop first, otherwise the procedure cannot execute because the CSV file is used by another process.

My code above is *error-free* although for some reason the WPF application never stops even though the `MessageBox` is generated.

---

Below you can see when the file is opened and the `MessageBox` is correctly generated.

[image]

---

But when I click **OK** I get the following error from the stored procedure in SQL Server:

[image]

---

This error should not have been generated because the application should have stopped with a `return` statement.

What is the mistake here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The error should not have been generated in the first place because
> the application should have stopped with the return statement. What am
> I doing wrong?

The problem lies withing your assumption that you are actually returning out of the `LoadFilesMethod()` but you aren't.

Return statements only return out of the function you are currently in. So with the return statements you have in your `CloseFileIfOpen()` method, you are only returning out of `CloseFileIfOpen()` and then continue with the rest of the code in your `LoadFilesMethod()`.

To fix that you can just use the boolean from the `CheckFileIsOpen()` Method and use that to return out of the `LoadFilesMethod()`. Instead of creating a seperate function for that.

**Example:**

```cs
public static int LoadFilesMethod(string connectionString, string ProcedureName, IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object> parameters, string filenamepath)
{
    .....

    // Check if File is already open (true if it is, false if it isn't)
    bool IsFileOpen = CheckFileIsOpen(filenamepath);
    
    // Is File already in use then,
    if (IsFileOpen) {
        // return out of this function
        return 0;
    }
    
    .....
}
```

I would also advise you to switch the bools you return in this function to accurately represent it's name.

**CheckFileIsOpen:** File is open --> `true`, File not open --> `false`

```cs
public static bool CheckFileIsOpen(string filenamepath)
{
    try
    {
        using (fs = new FileStream(filenamepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("File is in use!! Close it and try again");
        return true;
    }
    
    .....
}
```

---

**Return:**

As said earlier if you use [`return`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/return) you exit the current function you are in. If that function has a return type tough (eg. `int`, `bool` etc.), you need to return a value as well.

You can only return no value if the function is a `void`.

Comment: There's no reason to define `fs` ouside the `using` block

Comment: @MathewHD ty for the answer. Actually I have already tried this and I was discouraged by the error it generated when i call return inside the LoadFilesMethod(), my VS 2019 editor writes that ```return;``` that should be an ```object of a type convertible int is required``` and I thought this is logical because LoadFilesMethod() returns int. Isn't it weird?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos so I just have to omit the finally clause, right?

Comment: `using (var fs = new FileStream(...)){...}` is enough. Don't declare `fs` outside the `using` block at all

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I did the change as you proposed in your comments

Comment: Just make sure to check after calling the function if it returened 0 (so it failed) and then don't process the data.

Comment: @MathewHD ty for the edit I have also made in my code. I will try and let you know. I am new in coding with C# and it was really weird to me if return 0 would stop the program. So I was discouraged and never tested it. let me try it.

Comment: I'll add some text to explain return if it helps you :D

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help MathewHD. Appreciate the explanation :) The solution works as expected.